# ¿Por qué el valor asignado en el arreglo fuera del for se repite? FILE en c++

Tags: c++, array

Tengo un problema al leer un archivo, tengo que leer correos y guardarlos en un arreglo para posteriormente ordenarlos, estoy usando fgets() para leer lineas completas, pero al momento de guardar los datos en un arreglo e imprimirlo dentro del for está todo normal, pero al acceder fuera de él en todas la posiciones está solo la última línea, a qué se deberá?

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
  char cad[50]={};
  char *cadenas[4]={};
  int cont = 0;

  FILE *stream = fopen("miembros.txt", "r");
  if (stream == NULL){
    printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo");
  }else{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 && fgets(cad,30,stream) != NULL; i++){
      cadenas[i] = cad;

      printf("%s",cadenas[i]); //Este print, imprime todo correctamente
    }
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      cadenas[i];
      printf("%s",cadenas[i]);//Este print imprime la ultima linea en todas las posiciones del array
    }

  return 0;
}
```

La impresion dentro del for del else imprime algo como:
correo1
correo2
correo3
correo4

Mientras que lo que está fuera de él imrpime:
correo4
correo4
correo4
correo4

Comment: cad siempre tiene el mismo valor, no es un puntero, es una cadena estatica.. por lo tanto cuando le asignas cad a cada item de cadena, todas apuntan a la misma, y siempre es la ultima.. dentro del for no te pasa, porque esta cambiando cad

Answer (score 0):

Es lo que tiene usar características propias de C en C++.

Tu estás asumiendo que la siguiente línea:

```
cadenas[i] = cad;
```

Mágicamente hará las siguientes operaciones:

- Crea una reserva de memoria en `cadenas[i]`
- Copia el contenido de `cad` en `cadenas[i]`

Lamentablemente eso no sucede. `cadenas[i]` es un puntero a `char` y lo que hace esa asignación es, simplemente, dejar a `cadenas[i]` apuntando a la dirección de memoria de `cad`.

Es decir, después de las 4 iteraciones, **todos** los elementos de `cadenas` apuntarán al mismo sitio, la variable `cad`.

Si esto fuese C te diría que la solución más sencilla sería darle un tamaño a cada elemento de `cadenas`:

```
char cadenas[4][50];
```

y forzar la copia de la información:

```
strcpy(cadenas[i], cad);
```

Peeeero como has puesto la etiqueta de C++, lo normal entonces sería usar la clase `std::string`. Esta clase, a diferencia de `char*`, sí que incluye numerosas utilidades que te facilitan la vida, como una sobrecarga del operador de asignación:

```
std::string cadenas[4];

// ...

cadenas[i] = cad;
```

Usando `std::string` verás como ya no sufres el problema de los datos repetidos.